# Django Templating: how to access properties of the first item in a list

Tags: django, django-templates

Pretty simple. I have a Python list that I am passing to a Django template.

I can specifically access the first item in this list using

```
{{ thelist|first }}
```

However, I also want to access a property of that item... ideally you'd think it would look like this:

```
{{ thelist|first.propertyName }}
```

But alas, it does not.

Is there any template solution to this, or am I just going to find myself passing an extra template variable...

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You can access any item in a list via its index number. In a template this works the same as any other property lookup:

```
{{ thelist.0.propertyName }}
```

Comment: Hmm. this doesnt work with an inline_admin_formset however. I guess the iterator doesnt work how I expect it to.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Could you check my question related to template/view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791375/how-to-use-render-to-response-to-render-a-html-page-within-div-in-django ?

Comment: This is much better than a `for` loop to go through each of the error messages. Thanks!

Comment: And `thelist.-1.propertyName` for the last item?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work unfortunately, Django can't parse that. You would need to use the `with` tag along with `|last`, as Mark suggests in the other answer.

Comment: An alternative to using the `with` tag would be creating a custom filter, something like a "get" filter: `def get(d, k): return d.get(k, None)`. After loading that filter: `{{ thelist|last|get:"propertyName" }}`. Find out more about custom filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 39):

You can combine the `with` template tag with the `first` template filter to access the property.

```
{% with thelist|first as first_object %}
    {{ first_object.propertyname }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: For a dictionary, first returns a tuple for the key/value pair, it's a bit ugly but I added another with statement to get just the values.
{% with thelist|first as first_object %}{% with first_object.1 as object %}{{ object }}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/61539/mark-lavin you saved my day

Answer (score 25):

If you're trying to access a manytomany field, remember to add `all`, so it will look like `object.m2m_field.all.0.item_property`

Comment: Could give you +10 mentioning "all", you saved my day ;)

Comment: I always forget about this.

Answer (score 1):

a potentially clearer answer/syntax for accessing a ManyToManyField property in an object list provided to the django template would look like this:

```
{{ object_list.0.m2m_fieldname.all.0.item_property }}
```