# Accessing the first object in list to have an optional property in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, schema.org

I'm trying to implement various [schema.org](http://schema.org) tags on a website run by Django. For pages tied to a specific article or item there's an obvious choice for the cover image, but for list pages there is not.

The models for the objects I have lists of each have a `cover_image` property, but it can be null. I'd get the cover image property for the first object in the list using [`{{list.0.cover_image}}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479206/django-templating-how-to-access-properties-of-the-first-item-in-a-list), but the first object may or may not actually have a cover image, in which case it would return null.

Is there a way to get a given property from the first object in a list that has a value for that property?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this...  (with a custom filter!)

```
@register.filter
def first_with_attribute(some_list, attr):
     """        
     Usage in template:   {{ list|first_with_attribute:"cover_image" }}

     """
     for thing in some_list:
         if hasattr(some_list, attr):
              return getattr(some_list, attr)
     return ''
```