# Select an item of the row in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

How can I select the third item of the row and add  tag only to it?

```
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {%for row in a%}
        <tr style="margin:10px">
            {%for item in row%}
            <td style="margin:10px">{{item}}</td>
            {%endfor%}
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin variable *forloop.counter* (which is 1 based) or *forloop.counter0* (which is 0 based). This is the current iteration in the for loop.

So you would do something along these lines:

```
<body>
  <table>
    {%for row in a%}
    <tr style="margin:10px">
      {%for item in row%}
        {%if forloop.counter == 3 %}
          <td style="margin:10px" class="marked">{{item}}</td>
        {%else%}
          <td style="margin:10px">{{item}}</td>
        {%endfor%}
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
  </table>
</body>
```

For more details, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/) documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Django and to do this you can use `list.2` or more generally `<listInstance>.<index>`.

Quoting another answer ([Django Templating: how to access properties of the first item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479206/django-templating-how-to-access-properties-of-the-first-item-in-a-list))

Django will attempt to find a match in the following order for dot '.' notation:

```
foo[bar]       # dictionary lookup
foo.bar        # attribute lookup
foo.bar()      # method call
foo[bar]       # list-index lookup
```

So, for your case row.2 would be equivalent to row[2] or the third element in the row list.